# JSON api on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm creating a JavaScript web app. I want to use Ruby on Rails to provide the API to the data in JSON format. I am writing the front-end entirely in JavaScript that will make Ajax calls to the API. This way, I will have a consistent data API when I can write different apps on different platforms.

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm not sure if this is a good approach. If so, could you help me point to a good tutorial to implement the back-end that I just mentioned? If not, please help suggest a good way.

Comment: I don't want to have anything to do with "haml" files since they look very like JSP pages.

Comment: What type of site you are going to plan/build ?

Answer (score 2):

Api example code : https://github.com/pigon-web-services/api-app/blob/master/app/controllers/location_controller.rb

How to use this api with javascript : http://pigon.ws/examples/jsonp?api=locationapi

Answer (score 2):

I didn't work with it yet, but the [Rails-API gem by spastorino](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) might be helpful.

Also there is a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem) on this, so you might want to check this out as a starting point